# Where can I find a list to all C++ functions?

Tags: c++, std

Once again I am studying C++ and hit the same wall: the reference list of functions. I could not find a complete list of functions implemented by the standard C++ headers, only websites with these functions shown one by one, separated by classes, templates etc.

I am looking for something similar to this:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=extensions-standard-c-library-functions-table-by-name

but for C++. Like:

```
 - <iostream> std::cin console input 
 - <iostream> std::cout console output
 - <iostream> std::cerr console unbuffered error
 - <iostream> std::clog console buffered error
 - <vector> .begin()
 - <vector> .rbegin()
 - <vector> .end()
 - <vector> .rend()
```

I am trying to avoid reinvent the wheel. My project involves calculations over 3D matrixes, file manipulations, string manipulations and so. If there are already functions that do what I want, I prefer to use the standard C++ library, instead of dealing with arithmetics of pointers. But first I need to know what C++ standard is capable of.

Comment: Many of the things in your hypothetical list are not functions.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/ would be your starting point

Comment: @BenVoigt Could you please explain?

Comment: @Den-Jason That's where I came from, but could not find what I wanted.

Comment: The first four are objects, the latter four are methods *on* a class. None of them are standalone functions. There are standalone functions in C++, but you haven't listed them. If you're coming from a language like C, then almost everything actually is a function in C. But in C++, we have objects, we have classes, we have instance methods, we have functions, it's more complicated than just "call this thing with these arguments".

Comment: @SilvioMayolo the latter four are actually methods of a class template, so it's not even a proper class...

Comment: For 3D matrices you might want to look at Boost or some other arithmetic libraries, but C++ itself doesn't have built-in support for that. For file manipulation C++ has had `<filesystem>` since C++17. For strings it really depends on what you actually want to do, it might be something that has library support or it might be something you have to write yourself.

Comment: @NathanPierson Nothing very special: load all strings from a txt file into an array of strings and show up messages accordingly to need. So the code will not be littered with string literals, and I can change the strings by updating the txt file instead of recompile all again. For 3D matrices, just calculate a bunch of variables from a 2D map (each position of the map equals to an array of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ Standard does contain a list of all names in the Standard Library.

I don't think you will find it particularly helpful, there are far too many to find anything by reading through the index, the organized hierarchy is much better.

But here it is anyway:

- [Index of library names](https://eel.is/c++draft/libraryindex)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is answered in Comment nº 3:

> The first four are objects, the latter four are methods on a class.
> None of them are standalone functions. There are standalone functions
> in C++, but you haven't listed them. If you're coming from a language
> like C, then almost everything actually is a function in C. But in
> C++, we have objects, we have classes, we have instance methods, we
> have functions, it's more complicated than just "call this thing with
> these arguments". – **Silvio Mayolo**

Therefore, the answer is not that simple. Classes have methods, which can be accessed by calling them accordingly to their respective template.
After understanding the problem, I would like to add the following list:

https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/cppreference_en/all_cpp_functions.html

https://pedrofigueira.pro.br/lista-completa-de-funcoes-c-std-e-stl-all-c-standard-library-and-standard-template-librarys-functions/